# CKAN - ckanext-scheming - add dataset button for each schema

Tags: python, ckan

I've been following the instructions and the examples to configure ckanext-scheming extension ([ckanext-scheming](https://github.com/open-data/ckanext-scheming)).

Now I am able to access by URL to the different schemas (as the example shows) that I've configured. At this time, I wanted to put these links in the main Dataset page in order to choose the schema of a new dataset before is going to be created.

Does anybody know how do I should to get a button of "Add new dataset" in the main window for each schema that I have defined? Someone knows if that is something implemented and configured in this extension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The extension does not cover this yet, but the template where the 'Add Dataset' button is defined is here:

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/templates/package/search.html#L16

You could play with that to add more buttons for different dataset types